# Galois, normal and separable extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, galois-theory, extension-field

Theorem: Every finite extension, normal and separable is a Galois extension.

Is the theorem  equivalent to: $\mathbb K:\mathbb F$ is Galois $\iff \mathbb K:\mathbb F$ is normal & $\mathbb K:\mathbb F$ is separable ?

thus,   $\mathbb K:\mathbb F$ is not a Galois extension $\iff \mathbb K:\mathbb F$ is not normal **or** $\mathbb K:\mathbb F$ is not separable, but only one holds, either normal or separable.

Comment: What's your definition of a Galois extension? One definition is that an extension is Galois if and only if it's algebraic, normal, and separable. But maybe you have a different definition and that's a theorem for you. Anyway, you can't leave out some kind of assumption of algebraicity or finiteness. (Normal and separable alone are not enough.)

Comment: @ZachTeitler : An algebraic extension $K:F$ is Galois if $G(K:F)^+=f(F)$, where $f$ is the monomorphism.

Comment: @Annelise The fixed field characterization (for an algebraic but not necessarily finite extension) turns out to be equivalent to algebraic + normal + separable. A first course in Galois theory usually only deals with finite Galois extensions however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a finite extension $K/k$ the following are equivalent:

> 1. $\require{begingroup}\begingroup\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}|\Aut(K/k)| = [K:k]$
> 2. $k$ is the fixed field of $\Aut(K/k)$
> 3. $K/k$ is normal and separable
> 4. $K$ is the splitting field of a finite number of separable polynomials over $k$
> 5. $K$ is the splitting field of a single separable polynomial over $k$
> 6. There is a one to one correspondence between subgroups of $\Aut(K/k)$ and intermediate extensions of $K/k$

For a possibly infinite algebraic extension $K/k$ the following are equivalent:

> 1. $k$ is the fixed field of $\Aut(K/k)$
> 2. $K/k$ is normal and separable
> 3. $K$ is the splitting field of **a possibly infinite family** of separable polynomials over $k$
> 4. There is a one to one correspondence between **closed** subgroups of $\Aut(K/k)$ and intermediate extensions of $K/k$

$\endgroup$

Comment: Does this theorem:  'Every finite extension, normal and separable is a Galois extension.' has the form $p\Rightarrow q$ or $p\iff q?$

Comment: @AnneliseToft An extension is finite, normal and separable if and only if it is finite and Galois. This is the most general usage of "Galois" which includes infinite extensions. Sometimes, when dealing only with finite extensions one drops the word "finite" and simply declares at the beginning of the section or chapter that all extensions are finite.

Comment: So is the theorem missing the ' finite' word  ? (Because only says ...Galois extension.  ). I am asking you this because I used that theorem in my last exam and my professor told me that I was wrong in my answer because the theorem is not an 'if and only if', the theorem has the form 'if..., then..' . And I lost 4 points in my exam , which is the main reason why I failed

Comment: @AnneliseToft That seems like the most likely explanation.

Comment: So at first instance, and talking in a rigorous way, we might say the theorem is not stated in the correct form?

Comment: @AnneliseToft The theorem is stated correctly.

Comment: where can I find the proof of the theorem (which book)?

Comment: @Annelise The problem is that given any book on field and Galois theory, these equivalences tend to be either scattered throughout different sections or not mentioned at all. One book I have that puts this in one place is Rowan's *Graduate Algebra: Commutative View* (Theorem 4.55) for 1,2,3,5 of the finite case (4 and 5 is trivial: if $K/k$ is the splitting field of $f_1,\dots,f_n$ then it is the splitting field of the product $f_1\cdots f_n$). Equivalence with 6 is generally a separate theorem called Galois Correspondence. (6 implies 2 is easy and often not mentioned).

Comment: hmm it's a long proof

Comment: I found one here http://web.mit.edu/~corwind/www/galoisthy.pdf but 'it's intentionally brief' anyway I'll try to understand it

Comment: T. Gunn I read the proof but I didn't understand most of it, help me to understand it pls :)

Comment: @AnneliseToft I think that would be too cumbersome to do over online text chat. Plus even in person I would to know exactly what level of knowledge and understanding you have. Even then, it could take an hour or more to fully explain.

Comment: ok so, what do you suggest?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Office hours are the first option. You can also make yourself a summary of the proof. Look for the key ideas. Otherwise, perhaps you can simply put the proof aside until later when you have more mathematical experience.

Comment: I would take office hours but we are on vacations at this time so it;s not an option

Comment: sadly I can't put the proof aside, I must understand it in less than a week, I will, but I still don't know how

Comment: @AnneliseToft If there is a specific part of the proof you want explained you could post it as a new question. Although, If you ask for people to explain the whole proof, without a specific question, I don't think that will be well received.

Comment: I already posted it, I posted two specific questions about the proof, but no one answer and I don't know why