# About the logic structure of a Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, galois-theory, extension-field

What is the structure of this theorem, i.e. has the form $p\implies q$ or has the form $p \iff q ?$

*Theorem:* Every finite extension, normal and separable is a Galois extension.

Comment: You have already discussed it in the post [Galois-normal-and-separable-extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355307/galois-normal-and-separable-extensions).

Comment: See also [Galois extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension): "a Galois extension is an algebraic field extension $E/F$ that is normal and separable". **If so**, the "finiteness" condition is not part of the def. Thus, a finite and normal and separable, being normal and separable, is Galois, but not vice versa.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA however Galois+finite $\implies$ separable+normal+finite

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Rewrite the statement as

> If $E/F$ is a finite extension, normal and separable, then $E/F$ a Galois extension.

Comment: so is a 'p implies q'

Comment: there might be cases were this side $\gets $ of the theorem holds, right? which is in the case were the extension is Galois and finite.

Comment: ... "might be cases" isn't enough; look into whether or not there are cases where the converse does not hold.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think I'm sure, this side $\gets $ of the theorem holds only when the extension is finite.